# RelativeSource. Изменение DataContext в DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

View:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
        <ListBox ItemsSource = "{Binding Kernels}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5">
                        <Button Command="{Binding RemoveKernel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding Kernels}" Content="Delete" Margin="5" Width="40" Height="18" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Title}" Margin="5" FontSize="16" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsVisualizationKernel}" Margin="5" FontSize="16"  VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </StackPanel>
```

Kernels это ObservableCollection. Во нажатию кнопки `<Button Command="{Binding AddKernel}"/>` Добавляются новые элементы в список. Если я правильно понял, DataTemplate меняет DataContext, которым является моя ViewModel. И поэтому привязки(RemoveKernel, Title, IsVisualizationKernel) не срабатывают(хотя вне DataTemplate они срабатывали). Я пытался сделать(всяка-разна) *RelativeSource* для RemoveKernel, но безуспешно, привязка всё равно не работает.

Comment: `Если я правильно понял, DataTemplate меняет DataContext` - не совсем, DataContext у вас один, в нем вы берете `Kernels`, а вот в `Kernels` вы имеете элементы, у которых свои свойства для привязки, это как папка внутри папки. В `ListBox` все элементы - это элементы внутри коллекции `Kernels`, вам надо перейти на уровень выше, либо внедрять ссылку на главную VM внутрь объектов `Kernels`, на уровень выше вы почти перешли, но не учли пару вещей: 1. FindAncestor ищет предка, а он у вас `ListBox`. 2. У `ListBox` нет `RemoveKernel`, он есть в `DataContext`, а значит надо `DataContext.RemoveKernel`.

Comment: Спасибо! А как можно получить элемент списка в CommandParameter?

Comment: Я ведь вам в предыдущем вопросе сказал, просто `{Binding}`, либо через точку `{Binding Path=.}` (вроде так), ну либо берите только нужное свойство `{Binding SomeProperty}`

Comment: Я вам дал ответ на все вопросы [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1122292)