# Mvvm ListView wpf как обработать нажатия в ModelView

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, mvvm

Как можно обработать событие  в MV
DelegateCommand.cs

```
 class DelegateCommand : ICommand
    {
        Action<object> execute;
        Func<object, bool> canExecute;


        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;


        public DelegateCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute)
        {
            this.execute = execute;
            this.canExecute = canExecute;
        }

        public DelegateCommand(Action<object> execute)
        {
            this.execute = execute;
            this.canExecute = this.AlwaysCanExecute;
        }

        public DelegateCommand()
        {

        }
        
        public void Execute(object param)
        {
            execute(param);
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object param)
        {
            return canExecute(param);
        }


        public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
        {
            if (CanExecuteChanged != null)
                CanExecuteChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }

      
        private bool AlwaysCanExecute(object param)
        {
            return true;
        }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
                <ListView Width="1031" ItemsSource="{Binding GetTopItem}" 
                           ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
                           Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="#DD000000">
                    <ListView.DataContext>
                        <vm:BookMainVM/>
                    </ListView.DataContext>
                    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></StackPanel>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                    
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            
                            <Border HorizontalAlignment="Left" CornerRadius="25,25,25,25"  BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#FF474747" Height="288" Margin="0,0,0,0" >
                                <Grid   Grid.Column="0" Height="Auto" Width="216" Margin="-1">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="49*"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="5*"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="18*"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Border CornerRadius="25,25,0,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                                        <Border.Background>
                                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding Img_src}" Stretch="Fill" />
                                        </Border.Background>
                                    </Border>
                                    <Label Content="{Binding Rate}"  Background="#FFBFBFBF" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Grid.Row="1" FontSize="11" FontFamily="Meiryo UI" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>
                                    <Border CornerRadius="0,0,25,25"  Grid.Row="2" Background="#FF8F8F8F">
                                        <TextBlock  Margin="6,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="2" Height="61" Width="190"/>
                                    </Border>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
```

Как при нажатии на элемент коллекции нужно как-то обработать это в MV и там получить данные Text="{Binding Name}.
Я уже перепробовал много способов и в итоге решил спросить

Comment: InputBindings пробовали? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/735522/218063

Comment: это не подходит так как если я напишу это в ListView.ItemTemplate будет другой DataContext а именно нашего Элемента коллекции, а не VM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, так:

1. В вашу VM для элемента списка положите свойство `Activate` типа `ICommand`, и пропишите в него экземпляр `DelegateCommand`
2. В вашем XAML укажите `InputBindings`:

   ```
   <ListView.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           <Border ... >
               <Border.InputBindings>
                   <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftClick" Command="{Binding Activate}"/>
               </Border.InputBindings>
   ```

Вроде бы всё.

---

Пример структуры VM:

```
class MainVM
{
    public ObservableCollection<ItemVM> GetTopItem { get; }

    public MainVM()
    {
        var itemVMs = new List<ItemVM>();
        foreach (Item item in Model.GetItems())
            itemVMs.Add(new ItemVM(item));
        GetTopItem = new ObservableCollection<ItemVM>(itemVMs);
    }
}

class ItemVM
{
    Item item;
    public ItemVM(Item item)
    {
        this.item = item;
        Activate = new DelegateCommand(o => MessageBox.Show(item.Id.ToString()));
    }

    public ICommand Activate { get; }
}
```

---

Если совсем не хочется иметь дело с несколькими VM, можно сделать так. Вместо `ObservableCollection<ItemVM>` выставить `ObservableCollection<Item>`. `Activate` положить в `MainVM`:

```
class MainVM
{
    public ObservableCollection<Item> GetTopItem { get; }

    public MainVM()
    {
        GetTopItem = new ObservableCollection<Item>(Model.GetItems());
        Activate = new DelegateCommand(o =>
        {
            var item = (Item)o;
            MessageBox.Show(item.Id.ToString());
        });
    }
    public ICommand Activate { get; }
}
```

Подправить XAML согласно рекомендации @aepot:

```
<MouseBinding Gesture="LeftClick"
              Command="{Binding DataContext.Activate, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}"
              CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
```

У меня такое работает, проверил.

Comment: ```<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>...                                                                                                                                                                                                        ``` DataContext будет класса Item но не VM

Comment: @yey_OK_cey: Я специально попробовал, нет, DataContext правильный, всё работает.

Comment: Минутку мы в ListView биндим ObservableCollection<Item>. Внутри <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate> будет DataContext ObjectCollection то есть Item. А у меня должно обрабатывать MainVM

Comment: @yey_OK_cey: Ну, я ж пишу «В вашу VM **для элемента списка** положите свойство Activate».

Comment: @yey_OK_cey не вижу проблемы прибиндиться и к главной вьюмодели `Command="{Binding DataContext.Activate, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}"`

Comment: @aepot: Так тоже будет работать, но будет сложность с тем, чтобы понять, по какому элементу был клик.

Comment: @VladD его можно передать в команду через `CommandParameter="{Binding}"`

Comment: @yey_OK_cey https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1122753/373567

Comment: @aepot: Технически — да, это решаемая проблема. Но если нам уж приходится решать такую проблему, то возникает вопрос, правильно ли мы всё делаем.

Comment: Зависит от того, насколько код внутри команды завязан на старшую вьюмодель. Если зависимостей много, проще добраться до нее биндами, чем тащить все зависимости в элемент.

Comment: @aepot: Ну это вопрос вкуса и архитектуры. Обрабатывать активацию элемента по идее должен сам элемент, а не его контейнер, но YMMV.

Comment: @VladD - Ну, я ж пишу «В вашу VM для элемента списка положите свойство Activate». У меня Item это контейнер там только поля Name, Img_src и тд... Есть Моя VM где я получаю коллекцию. И именно в ней нужно обрабатывать.

Comment: @yey_OK_cey: Мне кажется, логичнее было бы сделать Item более «активным» объектом, чтобы он сам себя обрабатывал. Но если очень не хочется, привязка, как предложил @aepot, сработает.`

Comment: @VladD надо при нажатии на Item как в браузере когда нажимаете по гиперссылке, открывалось новое окно, так что это как я думаю стоит отнести к VM. Она получит некоторые данные элемента, по этим данным будет запрос к бд, что бы сформировать страницу для выгрузки.

Comment: @yey_OK_cey: Ну да, это операция для VM, но по идее не обязательно для VM всегда списка. Вы можете точно так же сделать Item отдельной VM. Или можете не делать, и так и так будет работать.

Comment: @VladD И все таки как обработать нажатие если не получается  внутри DataTemplate

Comment: @yey_OK_cey: Ну делаете привязку как в первом комментарии @aepot, кладёте команду в VM коллекции.`

Comment: @VladD что значит  VM коллекции. Есть VM и Item. Можете написать пример, что бы было понятно

Comment: @yey_OK_cey: Написал пример. А почему только одна VM? Для каждого Item-а своя ItemVM.

Comment: @VladD А если у меня только Item и MainVM, где есть метод возврата observablecollection<Item>. Так что у меня нету ItemVM. да и надобности не вижу. Как можно ли это сделать в MainVM. Item этот как обычная ссылка на которую я хочу нажать, получить некоторые данные и открыть в новой страничке уже полную информацию

Comment: @yey_OK_cey: Надобность есть: раз пишете по MVVM, то логика Item'а должна по идее быть в его VM (то есть в ItemVM). По MVVM выставлять модельные объекты для View не правильно. Но если хочется как есть, а команду положить в MainVM, то привязывайтесь к команде как `Command="{Binding DataContext.Activate, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"`, как советует @aepot.`

Comment: @VladD можете тогда показать пример с 1 VM и с моим или с вашим DelgateCommand. Я пытаюсь сделать, но не выходит

Comment: @yey_OK_cey: Ну написал. Но я не очень рекомендую этот путь.

Comment: @VladD у меня вообще ничего не происходит когда я нажимаю. Можете скинуть весь xaml и DelegateCommand(если у вас не такой же как у меня)

Comment: @yey_OK_cey: Ну это не раньше чем вечером. А вы не забыли в вашу MainVM положить команду? И поставьте в `DelegateCommand.Execute` breakpoint, чтобы посмотреть, приходит туда управление или нет.

Comment: @VladD я поменял немного код. Я понять только не могу почему (Item)o не работает и пишет что нельзя преобразовать в статический тип Visual Style Element.ListViewItem. Ну это в принципе не важно. Мне хватает что оно передает в object. Спасибо!

Comment: @yey_OK_cey: Странно, а в каком смысле пишет? При компиляции или во время выполнения? Дайте точное сообщение об ошибке. И да, какой тип вашего `GetTopItem`?

Comment: @VladD Тип observablecollection<Item>. Item это просто класс который я написал. Xaml в вопросе. Пока что нет доступа к коду

Comment: @VladD при компиляции и версия у меня .net 4.7.2

Comment: @yey_OK_cey: А можно точное сообщение об ошибке?

Comment: @VladD                                                                                                                   
 State Error CS0723 Cannot declare a variable of static type 'VisualStyleElement.ListView.Item'                                                                             State Error CS0716 Cannot convert to static type 'VisualStyleElement.ListView.Item'

Comment: Аааа! Хм. Ну укажите не `(Item)o`, а полное имя с namespace, что-то типа `(YourApp.Model.Item)o`.