# Получение данных с кнопки в коде wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Всем привет. Прошу помощи в моей проблеме. Есть программа, которая при нажатии на кнопку должна открыть файл. В окне 2 кнопки, к примеру Telegram и Discord. Они имеют своё имя и тэг. Мне нужно, чтобы при нажатии на одну из кнопок происходило событие открытия приложения и чтобы кнопка передавала свои данные о себе во ViewModel, где будет проверка, к примеру, названия кнопки на совпадение с переменной пути. Код был такой:

> Xaml

```
<Button Command="{Binding OpenApplicationCommand}" x:Name="Telegram" Tag="Telegram"/>
<Button Command="{Binding OpenApplicationCommand}" Tag="Discord" Name="Discord">
```

> ViewModel

```
private void OnOpenApplicationCommandExecuted(object p)
    {
        string[] paths = new string[2];
        string Telegram = $@"Путь к файлу\Telegram.exe";
        string Discord = $@"Путь к файлу\Discord.exe";
        paths[0] = Telegram;
        paths[1] = Discord; 
        string tag = Button.NameProperty.Name;
        for (int i = 0, length = paths.Length-1; i <= length; i++)
        {
            if (tag == paths[i])
            {
              Process.Start(paths[i]);
              break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Проблема в том, чтобы в переменную tag получить имя или тэг кнопки, которая зайдёт по команде. Уже многое перепробовал и руки опускаются. Сам я в программировании не силён и только начинаю. Возможно взял на себя сильно уж непосильную задачу. Надеюсь смог правильно описать суть. Спасибо за внимание.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то так это делается

```xml
<Button Command="{Binding OpenApplicationCommand}" CommandParameter="Telegram"/>
```

```
private void OnOpenApplicationCommandExecuted(object p)
{
    if (p is string parameter)
    {
        if (parameter == "Telegram")
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. "Ответ полезен" не засчитывает, но вопрос закрыт.

Comment: @CaesarSpark https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1122753/373567 посмотрите на класс `RelayCommand`, он позволяет компактнее писать команды, вдруг пригодится.

Comment: Посмотрел. Я реализовал то же самое, просто у меня она называлась LambdaCommand. Почитаю ещё ваш ответ по ссылке, так как не до конца понял, как оно работает)